# Take the efforts or Make the efforts?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is there any difference in the meaning of "Take the efforts" and "Make the efforts"?

For example: "It takes efforts to quit smoking" or "Helping refugees to start again takes lots of efforts and time"

When you want to appreciate someone which one is better?

Comment: Could you share an example sentence for each of these? I don't think I've ever seen "take the efforts" used, but maybe you have?

Comment: It's normally singular *Make the **effort** [to do something]* (or *Make **an** effort...*). OR *Take the **trouble** [to do it].*

Comment: For example: "It takes efforts to quit smoking" or "Helping refugees to start again takes lots of efforts and time" @FriendlyRacoon

Comment: Is there any differences in the meaning of them? @FumbleFingers

Comment: A person _makes an effort_ to do something. A difficult job _takes a lot of effort_ to do.

Comment: Therefore sentence makes more sense: "I appreciate you for making efforts in the hiring process", am I right? @KateBunting

Comment: Yes, but simply "I appreciate your efforts" would be more natural.

Comment: Daniel: Please cite the sources of those sentences. (If you made them up yourself, then I don't think that they will be helpful for @FriendlyRacoon .)

Answer (score 3):

"Making... effort" is used when referring to effort that has been exerted.

> Example: "*I appreciate you making the effort*".

"Takes effort" is used when referring to the *effort required*. You can use it about effort that someone has already exerted by comparing it to what you know *would* be required.

> Example: "*It takes effort to do what you did*".